# Moss 2007 Site Action -> Site Settings have disappeared

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss, sharepoint-2007

For some unknown reason for the admin user of our Moss site (and all other users who had full control permissions) the Site Action -> Site Settings menu option have disappeared from the home page. I can navigate to it by going to mysite/_layouts/settings.aspx but I can't change anything it says I do not have permissions.

Any ideas what has gone wrong? I need to enable a WebPart that I have codded but I don't have the option to add it to a page.

To my knowledge nothing has changed on the system.I am thinking that maybe the VM that it ran on crashed and was restarted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we had to unistall sharepoint and reinstall it again. Acepting this as the answer as this solvedthis case for us. will make the question community wiki if anyone else has any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

IF the user logged IS the Site Collection administrator and still gets theses access denied messages, your Content Database seems to be locked. This happens during backups or when backups go wrong (get interrupted for example)

```
stsadm -o getsitelock -url http://server_name
```

if it is not showing as 'none', it is locked. fix command:

`stsadm -o setsitelock -url http://server_name -lock none`